# CakePHP Website Path Access Issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp

I am using `CakePHP 1.3` on my `LAMP Environment` for one of my project, and what shocked me suddenly about my website path issue for URL:

Its coming like this :

```
http://localhost/project/app/webroot/index.php/mydocuments/
```

While till now it was coming properly like:

```
http://localhost/project/mydocuments/
```

But I really don't know, what settings altered to cause this path issue.

I have 3 default .htaccess files which CakePHP provides like my folder structure is, one htaccess file is in root folder (outside app folder), one htaccess file into app folder and one more into app/webroot folder as you've described here, but still its path is the issue..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you use Apache and your Apache docroot is points to your app/webroot folder.

You need a .htaccess file in your webroot dir to make this work on Apache.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

If your Apache docroot is your app root (not recommended) you need another .htaccess file like this in your app root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer but yes I have 3 default .htaccess files in my folder structure, one in root folder (outside app folder), one htaccess file into app folder and one more into app/webroot folder as you've described here, but still its path is the issue..

Answer (score 1):

I second what wrdevos is saying. On top of that, also make sure that under the Directory directive of your documentroot (in your Apache config) the option *AllowOverride* is set to All, like this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
    # Other options should follow...
</Directory>
```

On most systems it defaults to AllowOverride None, which doesn't allow .htaccess files to be run at all.

Comment: thanks for your answer but well, my question is - till now it was working fine, but since yesterday path has been changed, so there is no change with my .htaccess files at all.. also till now I've not mention allowoverride in any .htaccess file as well, where i needs to mention this?

Comment: Are you sure that the rewrite module is still running? Try running apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES and see if rewrite_module is in the overview.